# Spring JPA - Issue while sorting on non entity column

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have requirement where I need to get the records based in join of three table with pagination(addition requirement are also there). So I have written a nativeQuery to get the records. Below is the sample query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT "
        + "a.GROUP_REF_ID as refId "
        + "count(case when c.STAT_CD in :userStatus then (c.grp_user_id) end) as numberOfUsers, "
        + "count(case when b.STAT_CD in :itemStatus then (b.grp_item_id) end) as numberOfItems  "
        + "from grp a left join grp_item b on a.grp_id=b.grp_id left join grp_user c on a.grp_id=c.grp_id "
        + "where a.stat_cd in :status and a.co_id in :cids "
        + "group by a.GROUP_REF_ID,a.grp_nam,a.GRP_DESC,a.co_id,a.co_nam,a.CRTE_BY, "
        + "a.CRTE_DT,a.UPDT_BY,a.UPDT_DT ", countQuery = "select count(*) from grp where stat_cd in :status and co_id in :cids ", nativeQuery = true)
public Page<Object> findByStatusAndCompanyIdIn(@Param("status") String status, @Param("cids") List<Long> companyIds,
        @Param("userStatus") List<GroupUserStatus> userStatus,
        @Param("itemStatus") List<GroupItemStatus> itemStatus, Pageable pageable);
```

Now the requirement is also that these records are to be sorted on any of the column in select part. So, if user passes `numberOfItems`, the records are to be sorted on it. But I am facing an issue here because if I pass `Sort` parameter as `numberOfItems`, spring prepends an `a.` before `numberOfItems` which results in error that `not able to find a.numberOfItems`.

Is there a way I can stop spring from prepending table alias while creating a query with `Sort`, or should I write my logic in a different approach

Comment: You are pretty close to the limits of what Spring Data is able to handle. You might try to wrap the whole select in another one: `select * from (<your current select) x`

Comment: This is what I eventually did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment an answer so the question can be marked as answered:

Wrap the whole select in another one: `select * from (<your current select>) x`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by creating a projection. (Kotlin was used but you’ll get the gist.)

```
class ShowRepository : JpaRepository<Int, Show> {
    @Query("SELECT s AS show, (CASE WHEN (s.status = 'scheduled') THEN s.scheduledStartTime ELSE s.startTime END) AS time FROM Show s")
    fun findShows(pageable: Pageable): Page<ShowWithTime>
}

interface ShowWithTime {
    val show: Show,
    val time: Date?
}
```

This allows Spring-Data to work its full magic, and using `Sort.by(Order.desc("time"))` works like a charm.

I’ve written it up with a little bit more detail here: [Sorting by a Non-Entity Field](https://blog.pterodactylus.net/2020/03/21/sorting-by-a-non-entity-field/).